# gnu slist execute error: lost of file .../bits/allocator.h: No such file

Tags: c++

I'm using Ubuntu. g++ version 4.7.2.

Can anyone help me with the gnu-extension single list? I compiled the stuff here and got a core dump when executed.

I debuged it and saw the core dump happend in the first line, where it throwed an error that I cannot solve. May anyone please help me with that??

the error code:

```
std::allocator<char>::allocator (this=0x7fffffffe4d0)
at /build/buildd/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/allocator.h:104
104 /build/buildd/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/allocator.h: No such file or directory.
```

This is my test code:

```
#include <ext/slist>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    __gnu_cxx::slist<char> li(&argv[1][0], &(argv[1][strlen(argv[1])]));

    if(argc != 3)
        return 1;

    std::cout << "SList: ";
    for(__gnu_cxx::slist<char>::iterator i = li.begin();
            i != li.end();
            ++i)
        std::cout << *i;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    li.remove(argv[2][0]);

    for(__gnu_cxx::slist<char>::iterator i = li.begin();
            i != li.end();
            ++i)
        std::cout << *i;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a build error?  Not finding a .h sounds like a build error.

Comment: @user1161318: The debugger is trying to display the source line where the program crashed, but can't find the necessary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're not giving any command-line arguments when you run it. It expects two: the character sequence to put in the list, and the character sequence to remove.

UPDATE: as mentioned in the comments, to pass the arguments to your program when using `gdb`, you need to use the `--args` option to indicate that arguments following the program name should be passed to the program, not to `gdb` itself:

```
gdb --args a.out xxyyxx x
    ^^^^^^
```

It initialises the list from the first argument `argv[1]` *before* checking that that argument exists; if it doesn't, then you'll get undefined behaviour. If you move the check above the declaration of `li`, then the program should exit with return code 1 instead in that case.

Then the debugger complains that it can't find the source file, and so can't show you on which source line it went wrong.

By the way, the C++ standard library now includes a singly-linked list, `std::forward_list`, defined in `<forward_list>`, which you could use instead of GNU's extension.

Comment: ... I'm not that ... challenged ... I wrote the test code myself. Using argv just for convenience.

Comment: @Adam: OK, sorry if I offended you. The only way I could get your program to crash was to run it with no arguments; it worked as expected otherwise. What arguments were you calling the program with?

Comment: Oh, forward_list is a single list?? Oh yeah. I thought I should write the implementation of the c++11 features on slist, now I can use the forward_list. Thanks!

Comment: I was not offended. You're really considerate, thanks. I used the commend line: gdb a.out xxyyxx x

Comment: @Adam: You need `gdb --args a.out xxyyxx x` to pass the arguments to your program rather than `gdb` itself.

Comment: Oh ... yeah ... It ... worked. Thanks. I do now admit that I'm challenged. Sorry for not reading the gdb's man first. T_T